# Android Studio how to put java classes to different folders without corrupting autosuggest?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I create new package to organize files and folder Android Studio is not suggest me classes which begins with _ this sign, what is the reason?
Should I create packages to organize java classes or there is anotber way which is not affecting Android studio.
Should I create new manifest file each time I create a new package
Answer should cover all solutions about above questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Android Studio how to put java classes to different folders without corrupting autosuggest?

1. Create the new package (folder)
2. Place cursor on the class definition that you want to to move
3. Press `F6` key
4. Select *To Package* and enter path to the newly created package
5. Press *Refactor*

---

> Should I create packages to organize java classes

Yes. Organize them in a hierarchy of packages. There are 2 popular techniques with self-explanatory names:

1. Package by layer (ui, services, broadcasts etc.)
2. Package by feature (login, main, settings, sharing etc.)

Here is a [neat guide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Organizing-your-Source-Files) on how to organize your android project, especially the part on [how to organize packages](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Organizing-your-Source-Files#organize-packages-by-category).

---

> Should I create new manifest file each time I create a new package

No. One manifest file covers one complete module. (The 'app' folder is one module. There can be many in a single project. In case of many, each module will have its own manifest file.)

Comment: How I can make different layout's folders which belongs to another package?

Comment: Keep the single layout folder. One does not need to create a custom hierarchy inside the 'res' folder, since it will never get too complicated.

Comment: Should I add new pakcage to inside of main package or not?for example inside of app->java->com.company.projectname or app->java ?

Comment: your base package stays the same. Inside it, you create further sub-packages.

For example:

'com.ibrahim.helloworldapp' is the base package of your 'app' module (Also mentioned in the manifest of this module as <manifest ... package="com.ibrahim.helloworldapp"> ... </manifest>

Inside it, you create further packages. Suppose your decide to Package by layer, then you will have something like:

com.ibrahim.helloworldapp.ui, com.ibrahim.helloworldapp.services, com.ibrahim.helloworldapp.receviers, com.ibrahim.helloworldapp.utils etc