# How to organize classes and layout

Tags: android-studio, directory, project-organization

so i was trying to find how to make sub folders for java classes and the xml layouts, I have a big project to work on and having to many classes and layouts in 1 folder makes it messy, is there a video explaining it? because when I am trying to make folders it wont let the app run

Answer (score 0):

managed to find the solution

for classes go here:
[stackoverflow guide for class folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857250/android-studio-how-to-put-java-classes-to-different-folders-without-corrupting-a)

for layouts go here:
[guide for layout folders](https://proandroiddev.com/split-layout-into-subfolder-in-android-5bf76f805e90)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should write a brief explanation on how the links addresses your question so it can help future readers, links expires so you need to at least explain what you have found and how it helps you.